# Chart Webpart: Show only integers?

Tags: chart-web-part

I have a chart web part using columns to display numeric values on the Y-axis and text values on the X-axis.

**How** do I set the chart to only show integers on the Y-axis? Right now it shows float numbers like the linked picture displays:

[image: chart example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation about chart web parts here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-chart-by-using-the-chart-web-part-HA101889211.aspx

Pay special attention to the section about "Axes and Gridlines", specifically:

"In the Interval box for the major grid lines, type a number that corresponds to the interval that you want to use for the major grid lines. For example, if the chart displays data in units of 100, you might type 100 for the interval to display major grid lines."